# specify field width in Print

Tags: output-formatting, alignment

I would like to format the output. For example, the following code gives

```
For[n=2,n<=10,n++,
  factorization =FactorInteger[n];
  length=Length[factorization];
  If[length==1,
    factorization =(Superscript@@@FactorInteger[n])[[1]],
    factorization =CenterDot@@(Superscript@@@FactorInteger[n])
  ];

  Print["n = ", n, " = ", factorization, ", number of prime factors = ", length];
]
```

[image]

But what I want is something similar to the following (but better alignment)

[image]

I know there is Grid, but I don't know how to use them in this current case.
Also, I prefer a simpler solution (if there is), such as one can specify a "field width" like in the C language.

Comment: How about a different approach using `Grid`? Layout-wise, this will be much more comfortable and powerful.

Comment: ... hijacking your code: `Reap[For[n = 2, n <= 10, n++, factorization = FactorInteger[n];
    length = Length[factorization];
    If[length == 1, 
     factorization = (Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[n])[[1]], 
     factorization = CenterDot @@ (Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[n])];
    Sow[{"n = ", n, " = ", factorization, 
      "; number of prime factors = ", length}];]][[2, 1]] // Grid`

Comment: I really need to understand `Reap/Sow` :P

Comment: @YvesKlett: Great. I didn't know how to use Grid because I used Print[]. Thanks

Comment: @Öskå yes, definitely - very useful stuff :D

Comment: I would encourage you to change your username into something more unique, which simplifies the interaction and enhances the overall community experience :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Grid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Grid.html)  is really quite useful for things like that if you can provide a finished list with results.

In this case I was to lazy to replace your procedural code (e.g. with `Table`) and just extracted the data you would have printed with `Sow` and `Reap`:

```
data = Reap[For[n = 2, n <= 10, n++, factorization = FactorInteger[n];
     length = Length[factorization];
     If[length == 1, 
      factorization = (Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[n])[[1]], 
      factorization = CenterDot @@ (Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[n])];
     Sow[{"n = ", n, " = ", factorization, 
       "; number of prime factors = ", length}];]][[2, 1]];

Grid[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you can start playing around with [`Grid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Grid.html) options to get a format of your liking.

Answer (score 5):

Supposing you want to print from inside the loop (not waiting for the loop to finish)
you can use `Grid` on each line with specified field widths:

```
 Do[
      Print@Grid[{{
        RandomChoice[DictionaryLookup["*"]], "=", 
        RandomReal[{1, 10}]^RandomInteger[12]}},
          ItemSize -> {{10, Full, 8}},
          Alignment -> {{Right, Center, Right}}],
    {10}]
```

[image]

Another approach for nicely formatted monitoring..

```
out = {};
Monitor[
     Do[  Pause[1]; 
          AppendTo[out, {RandomChoice[DictionaryLookup["*"]], "=", 
                         RandomReal[{1, 10}]^RandomInteger[12]}],
       {10}], 
                Grid[out, Alignment -> {Right, Center, Right}]]
```

Comment: Good point about using fixed widths anyway!